# How can I find the administrator of a website?

Tags: whois

The question above sums it up, but I will restate it here: What is a resource I can use to find the administrator of a website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't find it on the website, try whois

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find the admin of a specific website just try to write an email to:

- admin@somesite.com
- info@somesite.com
- root@somesite.com

Often these email addresses are redirected to the appropriate authority/person.

Furthermore it is possible use the contact form which many sites have and just explain you want to contact the administrator. The responsible person will know how to redirect your request.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not stated on the website, then you are out of luck.  Usually, there will be contact links to the owner or moderator of the site somewhere: could be on the bottom of the main page, or they could have their own contact page.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of whois you identify and contact the administrator of a web site.

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters, Sandy.  Can you expand this answer to make it more complete?  For example saying where you can find whois information or example output from whois?